# Como quitar los ":", para el FindOne de mi consulta en SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server, nodejs, sequelize.js

Ok, quiero solo obtener un objeto de mi base de datos, por lo que estoy usando sequelize, pero a la hora de la consulta, me trae ":80810", por lo que me manda un error en la base de datos: "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ':80810' to data type int.", porque el campo que intento consultar es tipo INT y como el el request, estoy enviando los dos puntos ":", ya cambia a nvarchar, pero no se como quitar los dos puntos(:) en el req.params.id_alquiler en node para, que lo no lleve de forma textual al script a la hora de ser ejecutado en el SQL-SERVER.

```
router.get('/rt:id_alquiler', exports.findOne = (req, res) => {
    const id_alquiler = req.params.id_alquiler;
    Rent.findByPk(id_alquiler)
    .then(data => {
        res.json(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
             message: 'Error', err
         });
     });
 })
```

Lo que me lleva a SQL:

```
SELECT [id_alquiler], [nombre_periodo], [nombre_tipo_exhibidor], 
[nombre_estado_alquiler], [marca], [nombre_sucursal], 
[fecha_ingreso_alquiler] FROM [View_RENTS_PDTs] AS [View_RENTS_PDT] WHERE 
[View_RENTS_PDT].[id_alquiler] = N':80810';
```

Pero si le quito los dos puntos : en (N'80810';), entonces si me trae el objeto. 
Entonces como lo ejecuta en la base de datos me manda error 500, pero es solamente pro los dos puntos ":", que están incluidos en la consulta del sequelize, saben como los quito o como podria resolver del lado de la base de datos enviandole el parametro string sin los ":"

Store procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ALQ_IN_RANGE_BY_ID]
@ID_ALQ INT
AS 
BEGIN
    Select *
    from  [dbo].[View_RENTS_PDTs]
    where id_alquiler =  @ID_ALQ
END
```

Agradecido con la ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde Sql Server tienes varias maneras de realizar lo solicitado.

Puedes recoger solo una parte del string, o solo unos caracteres de la parte derecha del string.

```
SELECT id_alquiler
 , nombre_periodo
 , nombre_tipo_exhibidor
 , nombre_estado_alquiler
 , marca
 , nombre_sucursal
 , fecha_ingreso_alquiler
   FROM View_RENTS_PDTs AS View_RENTS_PDT
   WHERE View_RENTS_PDT.id_alquiler = CAST(SUBSTRING((N':80810'),2,LEN(N':80810')) AS int);

-- otra opción

SELECT id_alquiler
 , nombre_periodo
 , nombre_tipo_exhibidor
 , nombre_estado_alquiler
 , marca
 , nombre_sucursal
 , fecha_ingreso_alquiler
   FROM View_RENTS_PDTs AS View_RENTS_PDT
   WHERE View_RENTS_PDT.id_alquiler = CAST(RIGHT((N':80810'),5) AS int);
```

Con el escenario del stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ALQ_IN_RANGE_BY_ID]
@ID_ALQ Varchar(7)
AS 
BEGIN
Select *
from  [dbo].[View_RENTS_PDTs]
WHERE id_alquiler = CAST(RIGHT((@Id_Alq),5) AS int);
END
```

Una manera de evitar la longitud de la cadena recibida y empezar donde toquen números, puede ser la utilización de las funciones patIndex y Len.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ALQ_IN_RANGE_BY_ID]
@ID_ALQ Varchar(7)
AS 
BEGIN
Select *
from  [dbo].[View_RENTS_PDTs]
WHERE id_alquiler = CAST(RIGHT((PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',cast(id_alquiler as varchar(7)))),LEN(@ID_ALQ)) AS int);
END
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, O sea, si funcionan ambas, pero edite la pregunta, si cuento con un store procedure, que es el que en concreto recibe el string, a la hora de incluir la variable en el store procedure, no acepta, como se puede hacer alli? muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Te he puesto la solución aplicada al stored procedure.